# How to export a Chart as png from HighCharts.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am using a C# MVC project with HighCharts.NET.
I can genearte a chart and everything works fine. But now I don't want to return the chart in my view but rather to save the chart as a png on my computer.

My Code which generates the chart:

```
            var chart = new Highcharts("chart");

            chart.SetTitle(new Title {Text = results.Title});

            chart.SetXAxis(new[]
            {
                new XAxis { Categories = results.Date.ToArray()}
            });

            chart.SetSeries(
                new Series
                {
                    Name = results.IndicatorName,
                    Data = new Data(results.Values.Cast<object>().ToArray())
                }
            );
            return chart;
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you want to process the chart without displaying it entirely? I think you can utilize POST request (not using any div as container) & return PNG file using `FileResult`.

Comment: Yes without showing the chart. Just generate and export

Comment: What do you mean with POST request and no div?

Comment: My first thought involves using POST request to controller action & returns PNG file. Since you're not intended to show the chart, no div elements used there.

Comment: I think you can set exporting options using `SetExporting`: `chart.SetExporting(new Exporting { Enabled = true, EnableImages = true, FileName = "[your file name]", Type = "image/png", Url = "http://export.highcharts.com", Width = 800 });`. But I don't know if this setting will export automatically or you still need `FileResult` action to export the chart image.

Comment: Thank you i will try that in a few hours

Comment: What is the URL parameter for? @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: URL parameter stands for defining URL to export the whole chart into image. By default it assigned to `export.highcharts.com` but you can define custom URL based on spec explained in DotNet Highcharts documentation.

Comment: If you want to export chart directly, without using browser, did you considered to use Export Module: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview?